# Why adsense is returning "Non-ASCII characters in origin."

Tags: php, django, wordpress, ads, adsense

Whenever I'm inspecting my Django websites this warning shows up
why I'm getting this warning on my website?
what does it mean?

```
 show_ads_impl_fy2019.js:343 Non-ASCII characters in origin.
 (anonymous) @ show_ads_impl_fy2019.js:343
```

Comment: Can you share url to your website? Looks related to some chrome [checks](https://crrev.com/2e5e1813e67fc6e07f7984f612ba99bffb240fb9/third_party/blink/renderer/core/feature_policy/feature_policy.cc#137) but unclear what causes it.

Comment: https://radioactiveguy.com/

Comment: Not getting these errors :( I wonder if it's because some country-specific issues. You are not getting any more info on what that "origin" it mentions?

Comment: I just applied for AdSense